# How to play next song and previous song?

Tags: java, android

Ok I'm having a problem with my music player rigth now I can play the actual song but when I want to play the next it gives me error

I have 3 songs in my directory raw

Here is my variables and my onCreate method

```
ListView listaCanciones;
List<String> list;
ListAdapter adapter;

MediaPlayer mp; ;

int posicion = 0;
Button play_pause, btn_repetir;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_explorador);

    play_pause = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnPlay_Pause);
    listaCanciones = findViewById(R.id.lv);

    list = new ArrayList<>();

    Field[] fields = R.raw.class.getFields();
    for (int i = 0; i < fields.length; i++){
        list.add(fields[i].getName());
    }


    adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this, R.layout.list_view_configuracion, list);
    listaCanciones.setAdapter(adapter);

    listaCanciones.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {


            if(mp != null ){
                mp.stop();
                mp.release();
            }

            int resID = getResources().getIdentifier(list.get(i), "raw", getPackageName());
            mp = MediaPlayer.create(Explorador.this, resID);
            mp.start();
            play_pause.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.pausa);
            //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Reproduciendo", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });

}
```

Everything works fine there, also I have a method for pause the actual song

```
public void play_pause(View view){
    if (mp.isPlaying()){
        mp.pause();
        play_pause.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.reproducir);
        Toast.makeText(this, "Pausa", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    else {
        mp.start();
        play_pause.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.pausa);
        Toast.makeText(this, "Reproduciendo", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
```

But in my method Next I don't know how to pass for the next song

```
public void Next(View view){
    if (posicion < list.length -1){

        if(list[posicion].isPlaying()){
            list[posicion].stop();
            list++;
            list[posicion].start();
        }
        else {
            posicion++;
        }

    }
    else {
        Toast.makeText(this, "No more songs", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What error do you have ?

In the `Next()` method, you're doing like you have a list of MediaPlayer. But you have only one player and multiple audio files, right ?
You just have to :

- retrieve the current position
- stop the current playing file
- launch a new player with the new position, like the one you've done in the `onItemClick()` method.

Comment: It says list.length 'Cannot resolve the symbol length'

Comment: use `list.size()` : http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#size()